# Adding an IF statement to jquery

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, slidedown, slideup

I am trying to add a slidedown effect to display a hidden div when i click an image and when clicking the same image when the div is visible i would like it to slide back up and make the content hidden again.

This is the script i am working with:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".content").slideUp();
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".content").slideDown();
    });
});
</script>

.content{
    display: none;
}

<body>
        <button><img src="image.jpg"/></button>
        <div class="content">
        stuff here
        </div>
</body>
```

I would like to have an IF content is visible than slideup() else slidedown() I am just having trouble adding to existing script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of jQuery's `.slideToggle()` method http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** To create correspondence between the buttons and the content they are toggling, use jQuery's `.next()` method to select the proper content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        // gets the button's immediate next sibling, 
        // which is the '.content' div (according to your html) 
        $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked great but i have 3 images i would like to toggle content. when i open the first one and then open another is there a way to close that first one?